# If email address is a login to my webpage -how should I design the very simple database behind it?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-performance

I have a web page with a login functionality. Logging in is based on email addresses. Also, I have to keep a basic user profile information like:

- street
- city
- zip code
- mobile phone
- country
- contact name

And the user's email and a hash of their password (of course).
What is more, when user changes any of his data, I want to keep track of it and store it too.
I know storing all of this data in one table is a bad idea, but I cannot come up with a better solution for now. Can you help me with that and suggest a way of dividing this data into different tables?

Comment: If you really have to stored that stuff I would leave it right inside that table. Everything else only makes things more complex. Just authenticate against the newest entry matching the email address and insert a new row for each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep all data in a single table is a bad idea if there are too many repetitive long data.

For example, if the name of the country United States of America, and there are lot of users registered with that country name, this is the best practice to create another table to keep names of countries with some code, and in the main table insert only code of country

Moreover, there is no guarantee separating them makes your database schema optimal.

If you haven't idea how to design database read about [normalization forms.](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)
This are the techniques proven by time.

In your case something like the following could be managed:

user(id, login, name, password)

user_actions(user_id, action_type, action_time)

user_specifics(user_id, address, phone, country_code)

country_name(country_code, name)

Comment: Thanks for the clue. What exactly is the action_type here? What could I store there? Also - why should I keep name in user and not in user_specifics? Because - if I get it correctly - login means email, right?

Comment: i like this normalization forms example

Answer (score 1):

You need several tables:

```
    users [id email timestamp]    
    user_profiles [id user_id name address city ... timestamp]
    user_changes [id user_id old_data_serialized timestamp]
```

Then you need to seek how to query tables relationally, you can search the net
there are many tutorials on it.

Your basic authentication should be based on email, but anything further relation in the 
table must rely on a never changing value, such as id.

About serializing data, I usually am not after serializing an aggregated data unit, but for the sake of simplicity and that you are a beginner, it might be enough, though I doubt yet about it.

Answer (score 1):

user(id, email, password, login name, mob. phone, zip code)

**email** is unique here. **id** is for default ordering.

**zip code** is a number (integer), there is no need to separate that, because you will need another number to define that zip code number which increases the complexity and memory space needed.

The remaining ones depend on the scale of the application and the average length of each info below:

**street name**: if street names are long and most of the users are from a less number of streets. 
**city name**: the same with street. 
**country**: the same with city.